# How to bind C# DataTable to JQUERY DataTable?

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

I want to bind DataTable get from Excel Sheet to a Jquery Datatable. And my aim is to bind all the columns for the Datatable as dynamically.
I have no idea how to bind the columns dynamically.

C# and Jquery is the code base

In this code, I get the data from the excel sheet as a Datatable

## region DataValidation

```
    public DataTable DataValidation(string dataExchangeSelectedColum, string entityvalue,string filename)
    {
        UA patsUA = Session["PaTSUA"] as UA;
        //List<DataExchangeDefinitionViewModel> dataExchangeDefinitionListVM = _mapper.MapToDataExchangeDefinitionViewModelList(_dataExchangeBusiness.ValidateDataType(dataExchangeSelectedColum, entityvalue, filename, patsUA.DBConnectionString));
        DataTable dataTable = _dataExchangeBusiness.DataValidation(dataExchangeSelectedColum, entityvalue, filename, patsUA.DBConnectionString);
        return dataTable;
    }
    #endregion DataValidation
```

I want to bind the above DataTable into jquery Datatable.
The above Datatable may vary that is the columns vary in different situations. so columns must bind dynamically.

Comment: Pass this datatable object to JQuery and parse it then bind it.

See this link http://live.datatables.net/fafuyeyu/55/edit

function getData(cb_func) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/ajax/objects.txt", //Here put your ServerSide function call
      success: cb_func
    });
}

it would be nice if you change the datatable to JSON

Comment: @Ratheesh let me try with this one

Comment: @Ratheesh i found an alternative way

Answer (score 2):

A small  change in my controller and create a partial view and load that partial view into a div

Here is the code

**Controller**

```
#region DataValidation

    public ActionResult DataValidation(string dataExchangeSelectedColum, string entityvalue,string filename)
    {
        UA patsUA = Session["PaTSUA"] as UA;
        DataTable dataTable = null;
         dataTable = _dataExchangeBusiness.DataValidation(dataExchangeSelectedColum, entityvalue, filename, patsUA.DBConnectionString);


        return PartialView("_ExcelDataTable", dataTable);
    }
    #endregion DataValidation
```

Created a partial view. Here it comes to play

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;
@{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> _excelDataRowList = from dataRow in Model.AsEnumerable() select dataRow;
}
<div class="table-responsive tableScroll">
    <table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <tr>
                    @col.Caption.ToString()
                </tr>
            }
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataColumn dtCol in Model.Columns)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataRow row in _excelDataRowList)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @row[dtCol]
                        </td>
                    }

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I load this partial view into a div where I wanted to display the table

Comment: Good idea. But did u try the same with server side processing  for jquery datatable?

Comment: @ChandanKumar, of course, we can do using serverside processing. Here is the advantage is my data is small size and it will create both Table heading and data in a single loop.

Comment: Dinesan : any hint how to make it serverside processing with c# datatable will be more appreciable

Comment: @ChandanKumar We can convert the data table to JSON using `JavaScriptSerializer`